# Google Datastore Transaction API vs. Datastore API when in a transaction

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I have been battling Google Cloud Datastore transactions for two days.

I am unsure whether or not I should use datastore.save or transaction.save when within a Google Datastore transaction.

Common code:

```
const datastore = new Datastore();
const transaction = datastore.transaction();
```

Scenario 1:

```
transaction.run()
    datastore.save(x)
transaction.commit()
```

Scenario 2:

```
transaction.run()
    transaction.save(x)
transaction.commit()
```

The documentation has examples where they use both transaction methods & datastore methods within the transaction.run & transaction.commit, but I cannot figure out if one is necessary or not.

Datastore.save would be easier for me but it seems weird given there is a method transaction.save.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct me if I am wrong, this is my current understanding**

If you want to write to datastore within a transaction you NEED TO use the transaction object to do so i.e. transaction.save & transaction.delete; datastore.save & datastore.delete will NOT be in the transaction, even if you put them in the transaction block.

If you want to read from datastore within a transaction, both the transaction and datastore objects will work just fine. Both will read based on the snapshot taken at the beginning of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The Datastore object is a client created for your code to connect to your entities. Whereas, with the Transaction object, you are creating an object based on your Datastore client to apply logic to your queries and updates.

In the case you mentioned [datastore.save](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Datastore#save) will be applied to inserts or updates to the specified object(s). [transaction.save](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.3.x/Transaction#save) will be applied to inserts or updates to the specified object(s) within the transaction and thus, transaction.save should be use within the transaction block.

Lastly, fetching entities should work (as you mentioned) with both objects as they both are a datastore client in the end.